# Angular RxJS not returning json properly from Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I am creating a CMS app and just for testing purpose, I get data using login button from Google Firebase. I am using rxjs to return the JSON properly but it returns a weird object with some kind of token. Please help me to get just the object without that token.

ajax.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AjaxService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  saveData(data: any) {
    const header = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.post('https://cms-app-dev.firebaseio.com/data.json', data, {headers: header});
  }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('https://cms-app-dev.firebaseio.com/data.json')
        .pipe(map(
                (response: Response) => {
                    return response.json();
                }
            ));
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AjaxService } from '../ajax.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    submitted: boolean = false;

  constructor(private ajaxService: AjaxService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
        'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
        'password': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.ajaxService.getData().subscribe(
          (res: any) => {console.log(res);},
          (error) => {console.log(error);}
      );
  }

}
```

[image: Gives this output]

Comment: You are using `HttpModule` which is deprecated you should  use [HttpClientModule](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2017/07/17/http-client-module/) instead

Answer (score 0):

```
let data=[];

onSubmit() {
        this.ajaxService.getData().subscribe(
              (res: any) => {
                     for(let object in res) {
                          data.push(object.email) }
             },
              (error) => {console.log(error);}
          );
}
```

Since you are posting data to firebase, it will store each object under a unique token. Hence it is an object in itself which has to be iterated over. So you cannot use your regular loop in the component template. So use a for in loop in the ts file and store it in an array form and you’ll be able to iterate over the stored data in your template. Hope that Helps!! Good Luck.

Comment: I just made a slight modification. Kindly check

Comment: I am getting `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` error

Comment: Sorry mate. Define data to be an array

Comment: Modified it in the snippet

Comment: @dummy `let` declaration is block-scoped , instead, it should be `public data=[]`

Comment: @Vikas that shouldn’t be an issue in the same components declaration.

Comment: what do you mean *that shouldn’t be an issue in the same components declaration*  you cannot declare a property with `let` or `var` at a class level

Comment: Class variable outside the functions are considered as properties, you can either declare by `private` or `public` accessors

Comment: yap, Vikas is right, if you use let at a class level,  you will get an error (Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.)  from typescript,  see [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

Comment: I was mentioning to declare the data variable in the same class like export class SomeComponent { data =[]; onSubmit() {} } so that was what I was referring to.